# Error when generating compile commands for tensorflow using bazel

Tags: tensorflow, build, compiler-errors, bazel, bazel-rules

I am trying to generate compile commands for TensorFlow as described in [this](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/tensorflow-internals-how-to-build-tensorflow-from-source-for-development-and-usage-855792a312e0) article. However, when I run `./create_compile_commands.sh //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`, I get the following error:

```
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=205
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from /media/nimashiri/DATA/vsprojects/ICSE23/ml_repos_cloned/tensorflow/.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --apple_platform_type=macos --define framework_shared_object=true --define open_source_build=true --define=use_fast_cpp_protos=true --define=allow_oversize_protos=true --spawn_strategy=standalone -c opt --announce_rc --define=grpc_no_ares=true --define=PREFIX=/usr --define=LIBDIR=$(PREFIX)/lib --define=INCLUDEDIR=$(PREFIX)/include --copt=-w --config=v2
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:v2 in file /media/nimashiri/DATA/vsprojects/ICSE23/ml_repos_cloned/tensorflow/.bazelrc: --define=tf_api_version=2 --action_env=TF2_BEHAVIOR=1
DEBUG: Rule 'io_bazel_rules_docker' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments shallow_since = "1556410077 -0400"
DEBUG: Repository io_bazel_rules_docker instantiated at:
  /media/nimashiri/DATA/vsprojects/ICSE23/ml_repos_cloned/tensorflow/WORKSPACE:35:30: in <toplevel>
  /home/nimashiri/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nimashiri/95da0dbf75375842593bb476d831db34/external/bazel_toolchains/repositories/repositories.bzl:37:23: in repositories
Repository rule git_repository defined at:
  /home/nimashiri/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nimashiri/95da0dbf75375842593bb476d831db34/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl:199:33: in <toplevel>
ERROR: /home/nimashiri/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nimashiri/95da0dbf75375842593bb476d831db34/external/io_bazel_rules_docker/container/image.bzl:550:31: invalid escape sequence: \s. Use '\\' to insert '\'.
ERROR: /home/nimashiri/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nimashiri/95da0dbf75375842593bb476d831db34/external/io_bazel_rules_docker/container/image.bzl:550:40: invalid escape sequence: \c. Use '\\' to insert '\'.
INFO: Repository bazel_skylib instantiated at:
  /media/nimashiri/DATA/vsprojects/ICSE23/ml_repos_cloned/tensorflow/WORKSPACE:23:21: in <toplevel>
  /home/nimashiri/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nimashiri/95da0dbf75375842593bb476d831db34/external/io_bazel_rules_closure/closure/repositories.bzl:81:21: in closure_repositories
  /home/nimashiri/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nimashiri/95da0dbf75375842593bb476d831db34/external/io_bazel_rules_closure/closure/repositories.bzl:203:17: in bazel_skylib
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  /home/nimashiri/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nimashiri/95da0dbf75375842593bb476d831db34/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:353:31: in <toplevel>
ERROR: error loading package '': at /media/nimashiri/DATA/vsprojects/ICSE23/ml_repos_cloned/tensorflow/third_party/toolchains/preconfig/generate/workspace.bzl:6:5: at /home/nimashiri/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nimashiri/95da0dbf75375842593bb476d831db34/external/io_bazel_rules_docker/container/container.bzl:18:6: compilation of module 'container/image.bzl' failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.102s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
    Fetching https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/0.8.0/bazel-skylib.0.8.0.tar.gz
```

Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: To Fix the above you should update the rules docker as mentioned [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/issues/1716#issuecomment-800975335). And also try the workaround if you still see the above [error](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/issues/1716#issuecomment-940723965)

Comment: I tried but still getting same error.